# Is there a rule of thumb on the relationship between the number of instances and the number of features?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection

If we build a classifier based on a very small number of instances (say, fewer than 300) and the number of features we are using is very large (say, larger than 100k features). If we decide to introduce a feature selection step before building the classifier, is there a rule of thumb on how many features we should choose?

Comment: I would think this problem is too data specific for there to be any rule of thumb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the type of your target variable. Frank Harrell gives some guidelines in his book, "Regression Modeling Strategies". You can find the discussion here (page 61):
[Regression Modeling Strategies](http://books.google.com/books?id=kfHrF-bVcvQC&lpg=PP1&dq=Harrell&pg=PA61&output=embed%22%20width=500%20height=500%3E%3C/iframe%3E)